# Xamarin and NSLinguisticTagger - bug or incorrect usage?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nslinguistictagger

I am trying to integrate syntactic parsing into an iOS app written in Xamarin.iOS (4.03) on Visual Studio 2017. To get my feet wet I created the simplest of apps.

- a single page app
- 2 UITextViews, one named SentenceInput, one named SentenceOutput
- a single button with an associated TouchUpInside() method doing the quick and dirty work.

The issue:

The lexical token recognition is all off!

A few sample phrase and the results (the ** high-lighting is mine for this post)

```
SentenceInput   | SentenceOutput
----------------|-----------------------------------
enter text here | Analysed text is 'enter text here'
                | **Adverb: enter**,here
                | Noun: text
----------------|-----------------------------------
draw a circle   | Analysed text is 'draw a circle'
                | Verb: draw
                | Determiner: a
                | Noun: circle
----------------|-----------------------------------
enter           | Analysed text is 'enter'
                | **OtherWord: enter**
----------------|-----------------------------------
enter text      | Analysed text is 'enter text'
                | **Adverb: enter**
                | Noun: text
----------------|-----------------------------------
draw circle     | Analysed text is 'draw circle'
                | **Adjective: draw**
                | Noun: circle
----------------|-----------------------------------
enter first door| Analysed text is 'enter first door on the right'
on the right    | **Adverb: enter**
                | Adjective: first,right
                | Noun: door
                | Preposition: on
                | Determiner: the
```

I didn't expect ML type quality, but these are the simplest of sentence and they are hopelessly off, unless I'm doing something very wrong.

*enter* is detected as adverb and even otherword, but not correctly as verb. *draw* is once correctly detected as a verb, then it's suddenly an adjective!

I haven't even dated throw anything more complex at it - with the exception of the usual "quick brown fox", which interestingly it got all right!

Here's the simple base code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;

namespace App
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        readonly List<Tuple<string, string>> words = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        partial void UIButton219_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            words.Clear();

            var schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.GetAvailableTagSchemesForLanguage("en");

            var options = NSLinguisticTaggerOptions.OmitPunctuation | NSLinguisticTaggerOptions.OmitWhitespace;
            var tagger = new NSLinguisticTagger(schemes, options);

            var range = new NSRange(0, SentenceInput.Text.Length);

            tagger.AnalysisString = SentenceInput.Text;

            tagger.EnumerateTagsInRange(range, NSLinguisticTag.SchemeLexicalClass, options, TaggerEnumerator);

            var items = from word in words group word.Item2 by word.Item1 into g select new {Tag = g.Key, Words = g.ToList()};

            SentenceOutput.Text = $"Analysed text is '{SentenceInput.Text}'\n";
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var results = $"{item.Tag}: {string.Join(",", item.Words)}\n";
                Console.WriteLine(results);
                SentenceOutput.Text += results;
            }

        }

        private void TaggerEnumerator(NSString tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, ref bool stop)
        {
            var word = SentenceInput.Text.Substring((int)tokenRange.Location, (int)tokenRange.Length);
            words.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(tag, word));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's about as simple as it can be for this demo. No attempts at optimisation or refactoring.

Is the NSLinguisticTagger really this bad? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It is not doing a dictionary lookup on the individual words, it is doing a probabilistic determination, so a "phrase" that exists of one or two words is going to result in really bad scores (use `PossibleTags` to review the scoring), now something "Enter your phone number" provides enough semantic information to provide decent recents. For short "phrases" like your examples a domain specific rules-based lexer (or parser) would for be sufficient and provide much better results then NSLinguisticTagger.

Comment: Dang. I was aware of the prob.det. approach but had thought it was *combined* with lookups for more precise scoring.

Comment: Any suggestion for a .NET lexer or parser that doesn't go whole-hog NLP?

Comment: There is `Stanford CoreNLP for .NET` (which is a IKVM translation of the `Stanford NLP` java code), but that might fall under "whole-hog NLP" ;-) and it is GPL-based and can not be used in any distributed software without a commercial license (unless of course you are open sourcing your app...), OpenNlp(SharpNlp) provides part of speech tagging along with many other features... There are numerous .Net based generic lexers/parsers but they would require you to define your domain specific rules. Google/Bing becomes your friend as this point ;-)

Comment: I looked into the Stanford suite of libraries and it looked like they were more like wrappers than whole re-implementations. As a result they wouldn't work in Xamarin.iOS. Unless I'm mis-reading something. Looks like I'll be looking at DSL lexers.